# nodejs mongodb official node package - async function won't return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write a simple function to grab the id of a specific instance based on matching criteria from mongodb using the official node package 'mongodb'.

My function works as I can console log the data but I am unable to `return` the data to use it as I intended to do as you can see.

```
const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Function for finding database id of device based on deviceKey, The database is written into 
// the code under the const 'db' as is the collection.

async function fetchId(deviceKey) {

    const client = await mongo.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
    const db = client.db('telcos');
    const collection = db.collection('device');

    try {
        await collection.find({"deviceKey": deviceKey}).toArray((err, response) => {              

            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(response[0]._id);   // << works logs _id
            return response[0]._id;         // << does nothing... ?
        })
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}

    // # fetchId() USAGE EXAMPLE
    //
    // fetchId(112233);   < include deviceKey to extract id
    //
    // returns database id of device with deviceKey 112233

// Run test on fetchId() to see if it works
fetchId("112233")
    .then(function(id) {
        console.dir(id); // << undefined
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
       console.log(error); 
    });
```

Why does my test return `undefined` but my `console.log()` inside the function works?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're combining callback code with async/await code in an odd way. Your function `fetchId` isn't returning anything at all, which is why you don't see `id` after fetching.

```js
try {
  const response = await collection.find(...).toArray()
  return response[0]._id
}...
```

If we weren't able to await `collection.find(...).toArray()` and needed to manually convert this from using callbacks to [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), we'd have to do something like:

```
function fetchId (id) {
  // this function returns a promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    collection.find(...).toArray((err, response) => {
      // within the callback, returning values doesn't do anything
      if (err) return reject(err);
      return resolve(response[0]._id);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: The `console.log(response[0]._id)` returns the correct ID but the `return response[0]._id` now returns `ObjectID {
  _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
  id: Buffer [ 92, 118, 15, 193, 186, 163, 208, 9, 82, 163, 110, 50 ] }` and not the id of the instance? What is happening lol

Comment: _ids in mongo are `ObjectIds`. Call `toString()` on it if you want it to be a string. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: `console.log` will call `toString` on its arguments, `console.dir` doesn't

Comment: `Buffer.from([ 92, 118, 15, 193, 186, 163, 208, 9, 82, 163, 110, 50 ]).toString('hex') === '5c760fc1baa3d00952a36e32'`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a value but handled like a promise is being returned.Please try this code.I had not tested it.

```
    const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

    // Function for finding database id of device based on deviceKey, The database is written into 
    // the code under the const 'db' as is the collection.

    async function fetchId(deviceKey) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const client = await mongo.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('telcos');
        const collection = db.collection('device');

        try {
            await collection.find({"deviceKey": deviceKey}).toArray((err, response) => {              

                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(response[0]._id);   // << works logs _id
                return resolve(response[0]._id);         // << does nothing... ?
            })
        }
catch(error){
  return reject(error);
}
 finally {
            client.close();
        }
    });
    }

        // # fetchId() USAGE EXAMPLE
        //
        // fetchId(112233);   < include deviceKey to extract id
        //
        // returns database id of device with deviceKey 112233

    // Run test on fetchId() to see if it works
    fetchId("112233")
        .then(function(id) {
            console.dir(id); // << undefined
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error); 
        });
```